# Two subdomains set up on Godaddy: one works and the other says only "pageok", why?

Tags: godaddy, multi-subdomains

I created two subdomains on my primary hosting domain: `wwdev` and `wwtest`.  I did this using the domain management interface. It created appropriate DNS entries.  Both point to the same IP address.  I created subfolders for both, `/wwdev` and `/wwtest`.  Both folders exist and have the exact same files in them.

For some reason, `http://wwtest.mydomain.com` works as expected, but `http://wwdev.mydomain.com` returns the `pageok` message.

If I ping both domains, I get the same result, so this isn't a DNS issue.

Both subdomains show "setup" as the status.

[image]

**Why does one return `pageok`?**

Comment: Where does/did the "pageok" message come from?

Comment: That's the document GoDaddy returns if you point a domain to their host without setting it up in your control panel.

Answer (score 1):

Not a great solution, but I deleted the broken subdomain via the interface and waited for it to disappear (took about 20 minutes). I then added it again and waited (another 20 or so).  After that it worked.  No other changes.